# Xcode 11 : ERROR: Identical key for two renditions

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcode11

Error when trying to run the archive task. This is after I upgraded to Xcode 11 (stable version).

[image: Error Message in the logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image with duplicate name was the problem.